# extend and __add__ methods in python

Tags: python

Hi guys I'm making a program that asks for 1 and 0 from inputs until there are 100 of those I still don´t fully understand the differences between extend and `__add__` but with extend it doesnt work.
I leave my code here.

```
bin_array = []

while len(bin_array) < 100:
    print("Print a random string containing 0 or 1")
    num = str(input())
    num_array = [(num[i]) for i in range(len(num))]
    bin_array = bin_array.__add__([num_array[x] for x in range(len(num_array)) if num_array[x] == "0" or
                                   num_array[x] == "1"])
    print("Current data is", str(len(bin_array)) + ",", str(100-len(bin_array)), "symbols left")

data = "".join([str(bin_array[k]) for k in range(len(bin_array))])
print("Final data string:")
print(data)
```

and the error

```
 line 9, in <module>
    print("Current data is", str(len(bin_array)) + ",", str(100-len(bin_array)), "symbols left")
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code, while clunky, runs fine on my end.

Comment: Yes sorry, i should have make it clearer, with the __add__ it works but with extend it doesn't. Thanks for answering so quick

Comment: You should *never* use `__add__` directly like that in client code. Use `+`.

Comment: `extend` mutates the list in-place and returns `None`. `+` (i.e. `__add__`) is like `append` and returns a new list.

Comment: Okey, now i get what i did there, thanks for the explanation guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append to the list with `+` or `append`:

```
bin_array = []
while len(bin_array) < 100:
    print("Enter a random string containing 0 or 1")
    num = input() #input is already string, no need to cast it
    bin_array = bin_array + [i for i in list(num) if i in ["0", "1"]]
    bin_array = bin_array[:100] #restricts the size of bin_array when input is over 100 valid characters
    print("Current data is", str(len(bin_array)) + ",", str(100-len(bin_array)), "symbols left")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, now i see it better

Comment: Sure sorry, it was my first question in stackoverflow